# Range input to change text and image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could you please see the snippet below and hint how I can split the text and images away from the `<input>` and `range-text`?

Here is what it currently looks like
[image: current]

and I want it to be
[image: New]

I first thought I could sort this will CSS (of which I can) but it's messy and I feel that it is more an issue with the JS to split the `form` and `label` from the image and text being updated.

```js
var $slider = $('#slider');
var $max_value = $slider.attr('max-value');
var scale = [0, 50, 100];
var range = {
  "0": "<div class='tours'><div><img src='https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff'></div><div><h3>Easy</h3><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eros tellus, venenatis nec commodo id, vulputate ultricies neque. Fusce aliquam volutpat lectus, et pellentesque augue.</p></div><div class='range-slider'><div class='slider-path'></div><div class='slider-fill'><span class='range-text'>Easy</span></div></div></div>",
  "50": "<div class='tours'><div><img src='https://dummyimage.com/200x100/b029b0/fff'></div><div><h3>Medium</h3><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eros tellus, venenatis nec commodo id, vulputate ultricies neque. Fusce aliquam volutpat lectus, et pellentesque augue.</p></div><div class='range-slider'><div class='slider-path'></div><div class='slider-fill'><span class='range-text'>Medium</span></div></div></div>",
  "100": "<div class='tours'><div><img src='https://dummyimage.com/200x100/2ab0a5/fff'></div><div><h3>Adventurous</h3><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eros tellus, venenatis nec commodo id, vulputate ultricies neque. Fusce aliquam volutpat lectus, et pellentesque augue.</p></div><div class='range-slider'><div class='slider-path'></div><div class='slider-fill'><span class='range-text'>Adventurous</span></div></div></div>"
};

$slider.after('<div class="tours"><div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff"></div><div><h3>Easy</h3><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eros tellus, venenatis nec commodo id, vulputate ultricies neque. Fusce aliquam volutpat lectus, et pellentesque augue.</p></div><div class="range-slider"><div class="slider-path"></div><div class="slider-fill"><span class="range-text">Easy</span></div></div></div>');

$(document).on('input', '#slider', function() {
  var $slider_width = $slider.width();
  var $slider_val = $slider.val();
  var $slider_fill = ($slider_val / $max_value) * 100;
  $('.slider-fill').css('width', $slider_fill + '%');
  $('.tours').html(range[$(this).val()]);
});
```

```css
form {
  position: relative;
}

#slider {
  width: 500px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #ddd;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.range-slider {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 25px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slider-path {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.slider-path:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider-fill {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 4px;
  background: #a1a1a1;
  height: calc(100% - 8px);
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transition: all cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0.3s;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0.3s;
}

.slider-fill:before {
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -2px;
  top: 50%;
  background: #4b4b4b;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.range-text {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -120%;
  right: -82px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.25s;
  transition: all ease 0.25s;
}

.range-text:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #333;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="range" id="slider" min=0 min-value="0" max-value="100" step="0">
</form>
```

Comment: why don't you add in the div class tours into your html and change the .text() val accordingly and the src attr of the image? The div will always be inserted regardless of what option is selected

Comment: Thanks @Juakali92. You mean to change `$('.tours').html(range[$(this).val()]);` to `$('.tours').text(range[$(this).val()]);`? I was originally working with that but changed to append `.html`. Are you able to give an example as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you will need to do yourself will be to style the slider using css. However this the core functionality in place. Hope this helps.

```js
 var scale = [0, 50, 100];
    var range = {
        0: {src : 'https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff', text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eros tellus, venenatis nec commodo id, vulputate ultricies neque. Fusce aliquam volutpat lectus, et pellentesque augue.' , rangeText:  'Easy'},
        50: {src : 'https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff', text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eros tellus, venenatis nec commodo id, vulputate ultricies neque. Fusce aliquam volutpat lectus, et pellentesque augue.' , rangeText:  'Medium'},
        100: {src : 'https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff', text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eros tellus, venenatis nec commodo id, vulputate ultricies neque. Fusce aliquam volutpat lectus, et pellentesque augue.' , rangeText:  'Adventurous'}
    };

    slideVal = 50;



    $('#slider').on('input change', function(){

        slideVal =  $('#slider').val();
        update();
    });

    update();

    function update(){

            $('.tours img').attr('src', range[slideVal].src);
            $('.tours h3').text(range[slideVal].rangeText);
            $('.tours p').text(range[slideVal].text);
            $('.tours span').text(range[slideVal].rangeText);
    }
```

```css
input[type=range] {
    width: 500px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #ddd;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tours'>
        <div>
            <img>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
 </div>
   <form action="">
      <input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="100" step="50">
 </form>
```